# Find Number of pairs (a, b) in an array such that a % b = 0

Tags: arrays, greatest-common-divisor

I am getting the solution in O(N^2)
here is my solution:

```
arr = [4,6,5,5,7,7,8]

count = 0

for i in range(n):

    for j in range(n):
        if (i!=j and arr[i]%arr[j]==0):
            count = count + 1
return count
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Satvik! Can you please state your *question* in the post? As it currently stands, it looks more like a statement than a question.

Comment: @satvik bansal Please specify what do you want to achieve. You want to reduce the time complexity?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check each item against another item, so the **general** code will be O(n^2).

You might be able to make it more efficient with knowledge of the structure of the problem.

For example if you have repeated values you can create a unique list first: this can have complexity O(n).

It might also be worth sorting the list so that you only divide larger numbers by smaller, but sorting is at worst O(n^2) anyway averaging at O(n log n).

You might be able to use clever mathematical properties depending on the number ranges to exclude a large part of the search (if the data has been sorted)